# Successfully able to ping domain outside of domain network, why?

Tags: networking, dns, ping

Hello Super User Members, (any help is appreciated on this one) I have a strange issue, I am able to ping my company's internal address (ex: hq.mycomapny.com) when I am on my Home network (WI-FI or Enthernet) and NOT connected to the VPN.
When I do a ping on the ip for hq.mycompany.com with the "-a" flag I also get a successful reply  that has the ip address in the repy with the following text appended to it ".deploy.static.akamaitechnologies.com" so it looks something like this (ex: a28-103-218-107.deploy.static.akamaitechnologies.com). 
Does any one know why I am able to ping my domain internal addres while not connected to the internal network or the VPN? and what is the (".deploy.static.akamaitechnologies.com") text in the ping reply.
I greatly appreciate any help on this.

Comment: There is a DNS record hosted on the company's external server that resolves that URL externally to a different resource. You are not pinging a local address. For example if a company hosts a local mail server, on premise it may be mail.domain.com but externally, that same URL will resolve to a public IP.

Comment: hmm ok, my understanding (I maybe incorrect) was that if I am outside of my company network and pining an internal address I would NOT be able to ping the address at all and would get an unsuccessful reply when pining that ip/name space.
BTW, once again thank you for any help.

Comment: With an internal IP - yes, but with a hostname, it can be different. If you know the internal IP of hq.domain.com and ping that, it wont return a response outside the network

Comment: that's the weird part, its coming back with a successful reply

Comment: It can come back with a successful reply if there is a wildcard catch all for your company's external domain, but it does not necessarily mean that it resolves to your internal server with that DNS name. For example, if there's a *.domain.com A record, anything that fits that pattern will return a result.

Comment: @Sorean, yes, you are absolutely right, ping  my.domain.com resolves to an address but it is not the correct one (not the address that it would resolve to if I was connected internally or via VPN), why is that the case?? why is it resolving to a different address?

Answer (score 0):

It can come back with a successful reply if there is a wildcard catch all for your company's external domain, but it does not necessarily mean that it resolves to your internal server with that DNS name.

For example, common DNS prefixes will be entries like:

- www.domain.com = 200.200.200.200
- mail.domain.com = 300.300.300.300
- *.domain.com = 400.400.400.400

Externally you are using a global DNS server, that is the public address book for DNS. So when you're looking up server.domain.com you will get 400.400.400.400.

However, when you are connect to your VPN or at the office, you are using your work DNS server which may have a record for server.domain.com which = 100.100.100.100.